# Twilio Call processor

Tags: php, twilio, phone-call, twilio-php

I'm trying to make a call queue, I tried multiple documentations and tutorials, but none of these are what I need.

Let's say my support number is 085-SUPPORT and the destination number is 09-1918231

When a customer calls 085-SUPPORT, they need to be forwarded to 09-1918231. Meanwhile the call is being forwarded and not accepted yet, wait music from a URL needs to be played. When the call is accepted, music stops and ready to call!

If there are people waiting in the queue, they all should be hearing the music until their call is being accepted. Since only one person can be connected to 09-1918231 at the same time.

Any help would be appreciated. Would be great if such idea could be made in PHP.

Comment: All of this is possible, but we're not going to write it for you. They have extensive documentation, including examples for your exact use case. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/guides/queues

Comment: As ceejayoz says, there is plenty of documentation on Twilio to help you with this, in PHP too. If you do have a specific issue that you are struggling with, feel free to edit your question and show the code that you've tried and tell us what is going wrong.